# Is there a way to automatically change an excel spreadsheet back to a template every night at midnight?

Tags: python, excel, command-line

Basically I have and excel workbook where the first sheet is detailed daily sales.  These values update a weekly report (sheet 2).  Every night I would like to reset all the values in the daily report back to zero, while saving the data in the weekly report.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this and if possible a clue as to how to start.  I have python and some command line experience but I have never automated anything before.

Thanks!

Comment: I did this without vba by just having the first sheet ready then duplicating it as the first step, rename as day of week or whatever and continue.

Comment: Use the `openpyxl` module to copy the daily report values to the weekly report sheet, then clear the daily report sheet. Use Windows Task Scheduler to automatically run the script every night at midnight. Then sit back, relax, and remind yourself that you're the best this world has to offer!